# Variable cannot be implicitly captured in template function

Tags: c++

I'm trying to pass a lambda to a function but I'm getting an error and I don't know how to get it fixed. Should I qualify the typename `F` somehow so that it knows the function must accept a single integer argument?

```
[cquery] variable 'f' cannot be implicitly captured in 
a lambda with no capture-default specified
```

Here is an example:

```
int twice(int i) {
  return i * 2;
}

template <typename F>
int foo(F f) {
  int i = 1;
  auto bar = [i](){
    f(i);
  };
  return bar();
}

int main() {
  std::cout << foo(twice) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You need to capture `f`.

Comment: Apart from capturing `f`, there are other issues. You are returning `bar()` but that's `void`. Did you mean to `return f(i);` from the lambda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says clearly that `f` is not captured in the lambda, so you need to do that just like you captured `i`. Also, your lambda doesn't have a `return` statement, so it returns `void`. That means you have an incompatible return type in `foo` which is declared as returning an `int`. Simply add a `return` statement inside your lambda.

```
auto bar = [f,i]() {
    return f(i);
};
```